# JQuery - How to get width or height of image which is automatically determined by proportion?

Tags: jquery, css, image, height, width

When I use "img" tag, if I set only the width and don't set height value in css, the height value of image will be calculated by proportion automatically.

But I found that I can neither find the height value with developer tools or get that value with jQuery height() method. Below is an example:

HTML code

```
<img id="cat" src="./cat.png"/>
```

CSS code

```
img#cat {
    width:10em;
}
```

jQuery code

```
$(function() {
    alert($('img#cat').height());  // It returns 0 because there is no explicitly declared height value
});
```

Is there a proper jQuery method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the image before it has even loaded. Try this:

```js
$("#cat").load(function() {
  console.log("Image height: " + this.height)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="cat" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a_400x400.jpeg">
```

Comment: Thank you! Um.. can you explain about that console object more?

Comment: @전세진 console.log is for debugging purposes, it just lets you log messages to check if your program is working. You can view the console in any web browser, it's better than using alerts.